# Making div contents scroll horizontally and not vertically

Tags: css, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

I have a div with some content, a bunch of thumbs, I'd like them to always be horizontal and any overflow gets scrolled horizontally.  I'd like the div to take up 100 percent width, keeping the thumbs a group centered, meaning when the page is wider then the group they stay centered and not stuck to the left.  I have a jsfiddle and can't seem to figure out why it's not working, it always pushes the overflow into a second row instead of allowing the overflow feature to take over.

http://jsfiddle.net/z5nEQ/1/ that's the fiddle and the code in that is:

css:

```
#wrapper{
  width:100%;
  height:90px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.box{
  width:50px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  float:left;
}

#container{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  float:left;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

html:

```
<div align="center" id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>   
</div>​
```

any thoughts on this? Thanks for any help
​

Comment: It's because of float: left and I'd say it's right behavior for that kind of situations.

Answer (score 17):

Write like this:

```
.box{
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    *dsplay:inline;/* For IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* For IE7*/
    white-space:normal;
}
#container{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/z5nEQ/3/

Comment: what exactly does the zoom do?

Comment: and yes that's exactly what I was hoping for, thanks so much, I'll accept it in 3 minutes when stack over flow will let me...

Comment: it's hack for IE7 because inline-block is not work in IE7 with ZOOM display:inline work like display:inline-block